# Unable to create a content type - A duplicate content type was found

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm having this problem and I didnt find any answers on the web.

I have a content type named "Document X" with the original "Document" as parent. (ID is 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF678614)

I already have a content type named "Document X 1" with "Document X" as parent. (ID is 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF67861401)

When I create a new content type named "Document X 2" with the parent "Document X", I get the error "A duplicate content type 'Document X 2' was found"...

I checked the ULS and the error isn't reported there. I can create new content type from any other content type (out of the box or others I created like "Calendar X") but I cant create new one from that "Document X". (And no I dont have any content type named like that.. whatever name I use, I get the same error)

Full error is:

A duplicate content type "Document X" was found.
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: b9d36bb8-1a8e-4ef4-bbd0-fbdf8e70d73b
Date and Time: 1/24/2011 3:00:36 PM

This error is happening on my content type hub site but I use and create content type on this site only. I dont create them using Visual studio, its in a production environnement and we have to create them with the Site Settings or Designer but both give me the same error.

I know I dont have much info to give here, I just dont know where to look first..

If anyone have **any idea** that could help me, I would really appreciate it as I lost a few hours on this already and dont know where to look anymore...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the ID of "Document X 2"?

Comment: "Document X 2" didnt have any ID as it has never been created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem, so if this can help some people some day.

Looks like SharePoint have some problems sometimes to update a field in the content database.

The field *NextChildByte* from the *dbo.ContentTypes* table is the problem.

Lets say I create a content type with ID 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF678614 with Document as parent (0x0101)

SharePoint will create an entry in the *dbo.ContentTypes* table.

When I create an other content type with the first one as parent.. The ID of this new content type will be 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF678614**01**) This 01 came from the *NextChildByte* field from the *dbo.ContentTypes* table.

Now SharePoint should update the *dbo.ContentTypes* table and set the field *NextChildByte* to 2 so the next content type created using the same parent will be 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF678614**02**

My problem was.. SharePoint didnt update the *NextChildByte* field so SharePoint was trying to create a content type with ID 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF678614**01** when it already existed...

In my case.. I finally have been able to delete the content type 0x010100ACEA2663B318874AA9192CA9AF678614**01**. When I recreated it, SharePoint did update the *NextChildByte* to 2 so I was able to create a more child content type after that.

EDIT: I found afterwards this blog post. Looks like this script could have fix it for me. This would be the best option since updating the database is not a solution.

http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/2011/06/21/a-duplicate-content-type-found-error/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue for a good while (the fixes mentioned here didn't work for me), I have managed to find an alternative way to fix it.

In my case this error was happening when trying to use a Site Template (classic templates).
Before saving the site as a template, I opened the site using SharePoint Designer, navigated to All files -> _cts folder and deleted the content types from the site level. In my case there was already a content type with the same name in the Site collection level.